# How to handle multiple inheritance when both inherited classes need a distinct member?

Tags: c++, multiple-inheritance, ambiguous, virtual-inheritance

I have the following classes:

```cpp
class ServoPart {
protected:
    virtual void doJob(byte* job) = 0;

private:
    bool moving;
    Servo servo;
};

// the following classes only have a constructor so I can use two ServoParts to inherit from
class Major: public ServoPart {};
class Minor: public ServoPart {};

class Arm: public Major, public Minor {
private:
    void move() {
        // do stuff
        if (target == current) {
            moving = false;
        }
    };

public:
    void doJob(byte* job) {/* do stuff */};
};
```

I can't use virtual inheritance (I think) because the Major and Minor need to control one servo each which can't be the same. However, when the Arm is done moving, it should set the `moving` member to false. Intellisense shows `ServoPart::moving`, when im typing `moving`.

Would this access of `moving` be ambiguous? If yes, how can I fix this? Is my assumption about virtual inheritance, that I can't use it because I have two different servos, correct?

Comment: Looks like a great time to consider composition over inheritance.

Comment: Inheritance doesn't feel like the right approach here, I'd consider composition

Comment: @user4581301 I used the "is a" vs "has a" method: The arm _is a_ servo part, containing of two servos. I think for now I'll store the `moving` state for both, Major and Minor, and combine them when checking the status.
I'll reconsider if I keep getting problems like this though

Comment: @al3c I went for inheritance because the arm is a servo part, containing of two servos. The `ServoPart` class also has an abstract function `doJob` which the Arm also needs. But if I keep getting problems like this, I'll reconsider my decision

Comment: re `doJob` I updated my answer again.  Having a virtual function is important information that changes the nature.  Be careful not to over-simplify the sample code!

Comment: `class pede {};` `class centipede : public pede, public pede, public pede, ... {};`

Comment: @JDługosz yes I can see that now. I will keep in mind for future questions. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it is ambiguous and the compiler will complain.
You can write `Major::moving` or `Minor::moving` within the code of `Arm`'s member functions to specify which you want.

I question whether you have a proper "isa" relationship here.  An arm is not a motor.  An arm *has* two motors.  You should be using composition here instead of inheritance.  Note that `Major` and `Minor` don't have any virtual functions so there is no reason to prefer inheritance.

Try:

```
class Arm {
   Major major;
   Minor minor;
   void move() {
     ...
     major.moving= false;
     minor.moving= false;
     ...
```

It is more obvious now how to refer to the components.  But with (multiple) inheritance it is the same idea.  I think also you are introducing the names `Major` and `Minor` just to get around the limit of inheriting more than one copy.  If you used composition, you can avoid that:

```
class Arm {
   ServoPart major;
   ServoPart minor;
...
```

Or, since they are the same type now, perhaps make an array instead.  This makes it easy to "broadcast" the same operation to all of them:

```
class Arm {
    ServoPart joints[2];
    void move() {
        ...
        for (auto j : joints)  j.moving= false;
```

## update

Your comment indicates `ServoPart` has a virtual `doJob` function.  You should separate that into a pure *interface* that has no data members, and derive your single-motor class from that.  Your composited class can also inherit from that interface.

```
struct Servo_Interface {
    virtual void doJob() =0;
};

class Joint : Servo_Interface {
    bool moving;
    Servo servo;
public:
    void doJob()  override;
};

class Arm : Servo_Interface {
    Joint joints[2];
public:
    void doJob()  override;
};
```

Note that the implementation of `doJob` in `Arm` can call `doJob` for each of the components it contains, but it is a separate function that does not have any automatic reliance on them.  Both single `Joint` and `Arm` instances can be treated polymorphically since they have a common interface.

Comment: I think I'll separately store each servos `moving` status then and combine both when the status needs to be checked. Thanks!

Comment: I updated the post to suggest using composition instead of inheritence.

Comment: Something I left out of the post which I should've probably added, is that the `ServoPart` has an abstract function `doJob` which takes jobs. I guess I could implement that function in Major and Minor and let it do nothing, but that wouldn't feel clean.
Basically, the Arm takes a job and sets each servos position. The Major/Minor classes can't do that themselves because the position depends on the position of the other part.